# How to interpret this Cumulative distribution function?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, survey-sampling

My colleagus has asked me to read through the ETOS material for estimating confidence intervals (published by Statistics Sweden) and point estimates, knowing I have a bachelor's degree in statistics. I know a bit about estimation but the terminology is partly new to me.

How do I interpret the different parts of this cumulative distribution function? The CDF, from a birds eye perspective, lets us know the probability of obtaining something equal to or less then a certain value (so $\theta$ in this case). In working with discrete observations, I think this can be interpreted as summing the probabilities for each observation times their value. And for a random sample the probability ought to be $\frac{1}{N}$.

So I can make this out part of this equation (we sum the value of each value below or equal to our value of interest times its probability) but what in the world does "I" mean? I can't really tell from the documentation.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what $U$ is, but $I$ is probably the *indicator function*, which is equal to one if the condition in its argument is true, and otherwise it is zero. Thus, it makes sure that you only sum over all those cases where $y_k\le\theta$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function ... multiple questions already on site already ask about this function, so (given that seems to be the main point of confusion), this is largely a duplicate

Comment: Statistics Sweden is a national statistical office and they do a lot of survey statistics. In survey sampling, $U$ usually denotes the set of all units in the finite population from which you are sampling (think U = your finite "Universe"). So $\sum_U$ is shorthand for summing over all units in the finite population, while $\sum_s$ often denotes summing over all units selected into your sample $s$.

Comment: Also, survey sampling uses $N$ for the size of the finite population, and $n$ for the sample size. So $\sum_U$ here should be equivalent to $\sum_{k \in U}$ or $\sum_{k=1}^N$. This $F$ is your full population CDF. By contrast, the sample estimate of the CDF from an unweighted sample would be $\hat F(\theta) = \sum_{k \in s} I(y_k \leq \theta)/n$.

Comment: In other words, I don't think this question should be closed, and I don't think it needs to be edited to reopen it! This is a reasonable question to ask as written, and it can be answered based on knowing that the equation's source is Statistics Sweden and knowing a bit of the standard notation in survey sampling. (The only thing I wonder is what "ETOS materials" are.) If mods could reopen the question, I can write all this up as an answer, and recommend readings where the OP can learn more about survey sampling notation.

Answer (score 3):

In concordance with [frank](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/592541/how-to-interpret-this-cumulative-distribution-function#comment1096319_592541), the expression possibly is meaning [empirical distribution function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function):

Define $\mathbb I_A: \Omega \to \{0,~1\} $

$$\omega\mapsto\begin{cases}1,~\omega\in A\\ 0,~\omega\in \Omega\setminus A\end{cases}.$$

For $\rm{i.i.d.} $ $\langle Y_i\rangle_{i=1}^N,$

$$F_N(\theta) := \frac{\# ~\textrm{observations}~ \leq\theta}{N}.\tag 1\label 1$$

Now, for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\},$ define $Z_i:= \mathbb I_{\{Y_i\leq \theta\}},$ that is,

$$Z_i :=\begin{cases}1,~Y_i\leq \theta\\ 0, ~
 Y_i>\theta \end{cases}.\tag 2\label 2$$

Using $\eqref 2$ to rewrite $\eqref 1$ as

$$F_N(\theta) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i}{N}\tag 3\label 3;$$

$\eqref 3$ is basically $\eqref 1$ but is now more comprehensive as it articulates clearly how the counting is going while calculating $F_N(\theta). $ As one can easily notice, $Z_i$ is a Bernoulli rv.

Also, as mentioned in the comment, unless more context is provided from the source/text, $U$ cannot be interpreted without speculation, but it plausibly could be an indexing set.

But the argument still stands. The text is talking about empirical distribution function, might be using it for non-parametric purposes.